# 'NOT BETWEEN' is not working in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Here is my Query

```
SELECT 
tbl_rooms . *, tbl_property . *, tbl_bookings.booking_Id
FROM tbl_rooms
JOIN tbl_bookings ON tbl_rooms.room_id = tbl_bookings.room_id
JOIN tbl_property ON tbl_rooms.property_id = tbl_property.property_id
where
(tbl_bookings.From_date NOT BETWEEN CAST('2016-03-02' AS DATE) AND CAST('2016-03-06' AS DATE)
 AND tbl_bookings.To_date NOT BETWEEN CAST('2016-03-02' AS DATE) AND CAST('2016-03-06' AS DATE) 
 AND tbl_bookings.From_date > CAST('2016-03-06' AS DATE) 
 AND tbl_bookings.To_date > CAST('2016-03-06' AS DATE) AND tbl_property.Ref_Property_Type_Property_Type_Id = 1)
```

When I tried to implement this query inside **codeigniter** 
I found that BETWEEN gives result but NOT BETWEEN does not give any result,
need help...

edit -codeigniter implementation

```
    $where="tbl_bookings.From_date NOT BETWEEN CAST('2016-03-02' AS DATE) AND CAST('2016-03-06' AS DATE)
    AND tbl_bookings.To_date NOT BETWEEN CAST('2016-03-02' AS DATE) AND CAST('2016-03-06' AS DATE) 
    AND tbl_bookings.From_date > CAST('2016-03-06' AS DATE)
    AND tbl_bookings.To_date > CAST('2016-03-06' AS DATE)";     
    $this->db->select('tbl_rooms.*,tbl_property.*,tbl_bookings.booking_Id');
    $this->db->from('tbl_rooms');
    $this->db->join('tbl_bookings','tbl_rooms.room_id = tbl_bookings.room_id' );
    $this->db->join('tbl_property','tbl_rooms.property_id = tbl_property.property_id' );
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->where('tbl_property.Ref_Property_Type_Property_Type_Id',1);
    $query=$this->db->get();
```

Comment: are you sure you have a record meeting this criteria?  Better yet can you show us an example of a record you expect to be returned?

Comment: when I remove NOT keyword the query gives result

Comment: Do you get a sql or or just empty result set?

Comment: When removed NOT keyword I get empty result set

Comment: Ok so I have a single record in a database.  When I use criteria to select it I get it, when I add not I don't get any records.... DUH... there's only one record, and it can only be in one of the two.  So saying the same thing doesn't mean that you have a record matching the NOT criteria.

Comment: ok I adjusted db now for both condition there are records available in db
 but the same case is hapenning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the two `NOT BETWEEN AND` are useless, which overlap with the following two conditions.

The query is equivalent with the following one:

```
SELECT 
tbl_rooms . *, tbl_property . *, tbl_bookings.booking_Id
FROM tbl_rooms
JOIN tbl_bookings ON tbl_rooms.room_id = tbl_bookings.room_id
JOIN tbl_property ON tbl_rooms.property_id = tbl_property.property_id
where
    tbl_bookings.From_date > CAST('2016-03-06' AS DATE) AND 
    tbl_bookings.To_date > CAST('2016-03-06' AS DATE) AND 
    tbl_property.Ref_Property_Type_Property_Type_Id = 1;
```

For the empty set you get, it may be filter out by the join condition.

You can verify that by removing the whole `where` clause. If that is the case, you need to do adjustment accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, my query was wrong which was not giving the result, thank you, it helped me to find the right answer, I was looking for property ids which are available in given dates